# How to use different drawables only during a xml animation with a image view widget (android)

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

How do you make the image view use a specific drawable only for a animation and then revert back to the previous drawable after the animation is finished. My attempt at this is below and it does not work because it never shows the "alt_die_" drawable during the animation. The only drawable thats is shown during and after the animation is the regular "die_" drawable. Note: I am new to android studios, so I am sorry if I did not use proper terms.

```
        String result;
        AnimationSet down_rotate  = new AnimationSet(false);
        AnimationSet up_rotate    = new AnimationSet(false);  

        // Fill the dice widgets with the images to be show during animation 
        for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++) {

            String image_name = "alt_die_" + dice_values.get(index) + ".png";
            try {
                InputStream stream = getAssets().open(image_name);
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, null);
                dice_images.get(index).setImageDrawable(d);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // Animate the dice by rolling and bouncing the dice
        down_rotate.addAnimation  (bounce_down());
        down_rotate.addAnimation  (rotate());
        die_image_3.startAnimation(down_rotate);
        die_image_2.startAnimation(down_rotate);
        up_rotate.addAnimation    (bounce_up());
        up_rotate.addAnimation    (rotate());
        die_image_1.startAnimation(up_rotate);

        // Fill the dice widgets with the images to be shown after the animation            
        for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++) {   
            String image_name = "die_" + dice_values.get(index) + ".png";
            try {
                InputStream stream = getAssets().open(image_name);
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, null);
                dice_images.get(index).setImageDrawable(d);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't format code on mobile but I have an idea,

Put the first loop in your code above in a method eg

```
Public void showDefaultDrawable () {

for () {
show alt_die
 }

 }
```

In second loop create an if to catch the end of the loop and call a the **showDefaultDrawable** method eg

```
for () {
show die
if (index == 3) {
showDefaultDrawable ();
}
}
```

Then you can just call the default method anytime you need it

Comment: The second loop is after the animation so why would I be loading the alt_die twice?

Comment: No you only get to load the alt_die once,when you created a method for the second loop don't call it until the first loop has ended I.e index = 3 then you can call the loop you put in a method